# Using external properties file with Springs as init.d service

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, service, properties-file

I am trying to run a Spring-Boot application as a init.d linux service using [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service) method provided by Spring. While the service will successfully run with

```
service vxmonitor start RUN_ARGS=--spring.config.location=/var/vxmonitor/config.properties
```

the external properties file will not load. The properties file is located in the same folder as the jar file. If I run the application using

```
java -jar monitor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=config.properties
```

the external properties loads fine.

My question is how to get the Springs service to point to the external config file, and if that is possible, how to integrate the location of the external config file into the service itself so RUN_ARGS doesnt need to be specified. Not sure what files would be helpful to help solve this problem.

config.properties

```
server.port=8099
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.valgoix</groupId>
<artifactId>monitor</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>vlgx-monitoring-svc</name>
<description>Client side server monitoring web service</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If there is another file needed please tell me. Thank you

EDIT:
I attempted to modify the service created by changing

```
arguments=(-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar "$jarfile" $RUN_ARGS "$@")
```

to

```
arguments=(-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar "$jarfile" --spring.config.location=/var/vxmonitor/config.properties $RUN_ARGS "$@")
```

except when I run the service I get the error

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /var/vxmonitor/vxmonitor.jar
```

written in the log file.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html  ...This page will help you ...

Comment: @VelNaga I dont see any documentation pertaining to external configurations for a init.d service. As I mentioned I am able to specify external configurations when running just the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a file URL as follows for `spring.config.location`:

`--spring.config.location=file:///var/vxmonitor/config.properties`